# is my laptop too powerful for airplane use?

Tags: laptop, power, charging

I have a laptop that pulls 20V 6.75A 135W and I have never once been able to successfully charge it from a plane.

Another laptop, however, has always charged without issue. That laptop pulls 20V 4.25A 85W (altho it seems to work just fine with a 60W charger)

What I'm wondering is if the 135W laptop's power requirements are just too high? If so then what is the highest wattage laptop I can reasonably expect to be able to use on a plane?

Comment: All we can do is guess. We don't know what sockets or power an aircraft will have available and an aircraft is not "computer hardware or software". If the craft has AC sockets then chances are it's fine, if not then *shrug*. Ask your airline/travel provider.

Comment: Most of the sources I found also claim that the limit is 75W per seat: [Guide to Laptop Power Ports on Planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EmPower_(aircraft_power_adapter)), [Do commercial aircraft have electrical outlets?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3474/1416), [Do Airplanes Have Outlets To Charge A Phone?](https://www.aircraftcompare.com/do-airplanes-have-outlets/)

Comment: *"Each pair of outlets at every row of three seats can support a combined total of 225 Watts... but there is 'enough power' on board to deliver 82 Watts to every outlet in the aircraft at any given time."* - Virgin Atlantic, 2010. https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2010/10/really-nerds-only-final-words-on-ac-power-on-airliners/65134/