# would disabling a GPU in windows reduce a laptop's power consumption?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, gpu, power, charging

So let's say I have a laptop ([ThinkPad P15 Gen 2](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/configurator/cto/index.html?bundleId=20YQCTO1WWUS1)) with a 230W power adapter, a 140W [NVIDIA RTX A5000 Max-Q 16GB GDDR6](https://technical.city/en/video/RTX-A5000-mobile) and an [11th Generation Intel Core i9-11950H Processor with vPro](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/213798/intel-core-i911950h-processor-24m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html). Let's also say I'm on a [plane who's power outlets only pump out a limited amount of watts](https://superuser.com/q/1506520/172193). In this scenario would disabling the NVIDIA RTX A5000 GPU result the power consumption being reduced from 230W to 90W? If I disabled the GPU then presumably the computer would fall back on using the
Intel UHD Graphics for 11th Gen Intel Processors that the Core i9-11950H comes with.

If it matters the OS is Windows 11.

Comment: No; It wouldn’t

Comment: These are **maximum** numbers. Your laptop won't normally draw that much power. Disabling a GPU won't reduce power consumption by 140W because it's not consuming 140W unless you're running it at full tilt. Same with the CPU.

Comment: Your computer is _already_ using the iGPU for most tasks. Only certain gamer notebooks don’t make use of [switchable graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU_switching).

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized dedicated GPUs in laptops can cause much higher power draw than having it enabled and not in use. Do not do this without verifying power draw (i.e. use [BatteryViewInfo](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html)). You might also have to configure windows to not schedule anything on that GPU (for me, it decided my browser should run on dedicated graphics).

Answer (score 0):

GPU's will consume more power as their workload increases. By disabling the GPU in device manager you will default the OS to use the native on-board graphics (if available) on your machine instead.

The GPU will still use minimal running power because it's still connected and still receiving power from the PSU, but by disabling the device you will certainly be stopping it from being used, which in turn will stop it from ever reaching it's maximum workload / power consumption capabilities.

If you wish to completely cut off the power you would have to open the device up and remove the power cable. This is not advised unless you are confident in computer assembly tasks, otherwise you risk permanently damaging your machine.

Comment: It's a laptop. There's no power cable. The GPU is most likely soldered onto the motherboard or maybe comes on a daughterboard. And even in a desktop, the GPU could still draw up to 75W from the PCIe connector and its BIOS would probably refuse to boot without additional power cable connected.

Comment: Correct, you would need to enable headless mode in the BIOS if you happen to have a machine that refuses to boot without GPU.

Comment: We're talking about using a laptop on an airplane, though. So definitely not a desktop. You should assume there's no removable GPU.

Comment: For the average consumer yes you have a point.

Comment: I mean... the alternative for an above-the-average consumer is to kill the GPU power supply circuitry on the motherboard by physically desoldering parts from it, because there are literally no modular parts in the dGPU area. It's a very risky operation that's not feasible for limiting the power draw for a single airplane flight with the intention of reversing it. I'd argue that physically cutting power for a laptop dGPU should be no-go unless you have a dead dGPU that prevents it from working correctly and you have nothing to lose.

Comment: What you say certainly is not the case with the laptops I service. Mostly all HP Studio G2's and G3's. The GPU's are held in with two screws and come straight out of a pcie slot (Nvidia T1000) and have no soldered parts. Not all laptops are the same though and as you say not worth doing for a single flight at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135841/discussion-between-gronostaj-and-mastaxx).